# MVC3 submit two model view with dropdownlistfor from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to query List from database which will be shown in dropdownlistfor in view, and chosen result will be post.

The problem is I'm using two models in view I tried more options

I'm lost with this, I don't know how to post it. Data are shown in listbox without problem. I'm getting this error when I try to post:

> "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'Item2.idcity'." System.Exception
>   {System.InvalidOperationException}

CityModel

```
public class CityModel
{
    public int idcity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string cityName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CityModel> citys { get; set; }
}
```

HospitalModel

```
public class HospitalShowModels
{
    [Required]
    public string hospitalName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string cityName { get; set; }
}
```

HospitalControler.Create()

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
        ViewBag.cityModel = new SelectList(DataAccess.DAL.showCity(), "idcity", "cityName");
        var tuple = new Tuple<DataAccess.HospitalShowModels, DataAccess.CityModel>(new DataAccess.HospitalShowModels(), new DataAccess.CityModel());
        return View(tuple);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(DataAccess.HospitalShowModels model, DataAccess.CityModel model1)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            DataAccess.DAL.insertHospital(model.hospitalName, model1.cityName);     
        }else{
            ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid options");
        }
        return View();
}
```

View.Create

```
@model Tuple<ProjektZaja.DataAccess.HospitalShowModels,ProjektZaja.DataAccess.CityModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Create Hospital</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.hospitalName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.hospitalName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item1.hospitalName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.cityName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Item2.idcity,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.cityModel)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model1 => Model.Item2.idcity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't strongly type a view to multiple models.  You need to create a view model which will simply be a composite class containing each of the other two classes, and strongly type the view to that view model.

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
  public CityModel CityModel {get; set;}
  public HospitalShowModel HospitalShowModel {get; set;}
}
```

Then strongly type your view to the view model

```
@ model Full.Path.To.CreateViewModel
```

And access the models properties appropriately

```
Model.CityModel.cityName //etcetera...
```

And bind it in the post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel viewModel)
{
  //...
```

Answer (score 0):

The model type in your view should match the model type in the post action. Therefore it should be a Tuple (though I personally wouldn't use that) or a new model type with 2 properties (one for city, one for hospital)